# print all lines with a specific char in last word using sed

Tags: regex, sed

Using sed how can I print all lines in a file that has the letter a in the last word?

I tried something like this `sed -n -E '/[ +e]./w\./p' < 'textfile'`

But Im very new to sed so not really understanding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use

```
sed -nE '/a[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*$/p' textfile
```

Here:

- `-n` disable the default printing of the line
- `-E` extended regular expressions
- `/p` print the addressed line

The pattern matches:

- `a` Match the `a` char
- `[^[:space:]]*` Match optional non whitespace chars
- `[[:space:]]*` Match optional spaces
- `$` End of string

Example input

```
this is a test
a
atest
testa
testatest
atest this is
testa this is
testatest this is
this is a test$%a
a word with special chars !@#$%a!@#$%
a word with special chars !@#$%a!@#$% bcd
```

Output

```
a
atest
testa
testatest
this is a test$%a
a word with special chars !@#$%a!@#$%
```